# How to use FindFit to fit an implicit function?

Tags: fitting

Now I am trying to fit some data with a implicit model function.

Firstly, I tried a toy example.

## Toy example with input and output

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.4}, {3, 1.8}, {4, 2.4}, {5, 2.9}};
fitfunc[a_,b_,x_] := y /. FindRoot[a y + b Log[y] == x, {y, 1}];
FindFit[data, fitfunc[a, b, x], {a, b}, x]
```

Mathematica gives the following warning message and answer:

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0. +1. a-1. x}
>    is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {y} = {1.}. >>
>   ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[a y+b Log[y]==x,{y,1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>   {a -> 0.986636, b -> 1.96879}

The fit seems good.

```
Show[ListPlot[data], ContourPlot[Evaluate[a y + b Log[y] == x /. %], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 4}]]
```

The fit result:

[image]

I have read the [documentation of Symbolic Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSymbolicEvaluation.html), and tried to use ***NumberQ*** in the function declaration, but I got the same warning message.

What am I doing wrong and how to solve this problem to avoid the warning message?

Answer (score 15):

One can always fall back on the definition of least-squares fitting, if the situation demands:

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.4}, {3, 1.8}, {4, 2.4}, {5, 2.9}};

{a, b} = NArgMin[Norm[Function[{x, y}, \[FormalA] y + \[FormalB] Log[y] - x] @@@ data],
                 {\[FormalA], \[FormalB]}]
   {0.9909829665303092, 1.952060702019563}

Show[ListPlot[data], ContourPlot[a y + b Log[y] == x, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 4}]]
```

[image: fit of implicit nonlinear model]

Note the use of [formal parameters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) as stand-ins for the parameters sought within `NArgMin[]`.

Comment: Note, also, that this version returns a lower value for the least squares objective function (`0.129153`) as opposed to the version using `FindFit[]`+`FindRoot[]` (`0.129416`).

Comment: +1 This answer is squarely within the spirit of the question: if the function is to be defined implicitly, then we are not emphasizing errors in either the x or y directions (unlike `FindFit`), but should be penalizing them in a symmetric way, which is what this approach does.

Comment: A 2 per mil in the objective function ... OMG

Comment: @belisarius, if you're angling for four good digits... :)

Comment: JM: Help yourself and remove some data points :)

Answer (score 14):

It's an evaluation problem. `fitfunc[a, b, x]` evaluates to your definition which is `y /. FindRoot[a y + b Log[y] == x, {y, 1.}]` this returns the error, since it cannot find the root without numeric arguments for `a` and `b`. To avoid it, you need to tell it not to evaluate your function until you have numeric arguments. I assume this is what you tried to do with `NumberQ`.

```
 data = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.4}, {3, 1.8}, {4, 2.4}, {5, 2.9}};
 fitfunc[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
             y /. FindRoot[a y + b Log[y] == x, {y, 1.}];

 FindFit[data, fitfunc[a, b, x], {a, b}, x]
```

Returns

> {a -> 0.986636, b -> 1.96879}

With no warning messages

Comment: Thanks very much! It works well now.

Comment: Of course, in this toy example, explicit solution is also available. $y = \frac{b}{a} W\left(\frac{a}{b}\exp\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)\right)$. Using `fitfuncExact[a_, b_, x_] := ProductLog[a/b Exp[x/b]] b/a` gives the same fitted parameters.

Answer (score 12):

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.4}, {3, 1.8}, {4, 2.4}, {5, 2.9}};
fitfunc[a_, b_, x_] := y /. Solve[a y + b Log[y] == x, {y},InverseFunctions -> True];
FindFit[data, fitfunc[a, b, x], {a, b}, x]
```

> When inverse functions are allowed, Solve solves for f[expr] first, then applies InverseFunction[f] to the result, equates it to expr, and continues trying to solve for the remainder of the variables.

Comment: This provides another method to fit a implicit function. I appreciate your nice answer.