# Numerically parameterize portion of $F[x,y]==0$

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, parametric-functions

I have a relatively complicated function of two variables `F[x,y]` whose zero locus contains a number of intersecting paths in the $x,y$-plane.  A problem I've been struggling with for a great while now is numerically parameterizing precisely *one* of these paths.  Meaning, I want to collect a large number of tuples $(x,y)$ precisely lying on one of these paths.  I include my code with all the preamble:

```
M = 1;
tau = (0.5) + (0.4)*I;
w1 = Pi/2;
w2 = Pi*(tau)/2;
inv = WeierstrassInvariants[{w1, w2}];
E2[t_] = 1 - 24*Sum[(n*Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n])/(1 - Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n]), {n, 1, 300}];
z[u_] = (I*M/2)*(WeierstrassZeta[u, inv] - ((1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50]*(u)));
WP[x_, y_] = WeierstrassP[w1*x + w2*y, inv];
L = -(1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50];
f[x_, y_] = Re[WP[x, y] - L];
g[x_, y_] = Im[WP[x, y] - L];
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
V1 = Quiet[FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.8}, {y, 0.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V2 = Quiet[FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.2}, {y, 1.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V3 = Quiet[FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.8}, {y, -1.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V4 = Quiet[FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.2}, {y, -0.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
A1 = x /. V1;
B1 = y /. V1;
A2 = x /. V2;
B2 = y /. V2;
A3 = x /. V3;
B3 = y /. V3;
A4 = x /. V4;
B4 = y /. V4;
Z1 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A1 + w2*B1], 50]];
Z2 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A2 + w2*B2], 50]];
Z3 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A3 + w2*B3], 50]];
Z4 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A4 + w2*B4], 50]];
m = (Im[Z1] - Im[Z2])/((Re[Z1] - Re[Z2]));
ListPlot[
  {{Re[Z1], Im[Z1]}, {Re[Z2], Im[Z2]}, {Re[Z3], Im[Z3]}, {Re[Z4], Im[Z4]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}
]

Zed[x_, y_] = z[w1*x + w2*y];

Quiet[ContourPlot[
        {Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y]]] - Re[(M/2)]) - Im[M/2]), 0}, 
        {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  PlotPoints -> 75, WorkingPrecision -> 50, ClippingStyle -> None
 ]
]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

In this final contour plot there is a nice smooth path from $(0,1)$ to $(2,1)$.  This is precisely the path I want to parameterize.  Now, I want to have the parameter be something like length along the path; the coordinate $x$ is an insufficient parameter because this curve I'm interested in, in some cases, may cease to be a function of $x$.

I should emphasize, the function whose zero set I'm plotting at the end is

```
Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y]]] - Re[(M/2)]) - Im[M/2])
```

I have a way of doing something like this in a very simple example which (almost) works.  Since I know exactly my starting point $(0,1)$, I can compute the gradient of my function, take a tiny step along the tangent vector, and find a new point on the curve near the tip of the tangent vector.  However, I'm worried this method will be wildly inefficient given that the function above contains fairly unwieldy modular functions and the like.  Moreover, by method goes bad at points of intersection where the gradient of the function vanishes.

In principle, the method described above should work, but even on an incredibly trivial function I picked, it takes quite a lot of time and quickly breaks down near intersections.  Can anyone think of an easier way of doing this numerical parametrization?

Comment: Much of the code in the question does not appear to contribute to generating the last plot.  Consider deleting unnecessary code to attract more responses.

Comment: Here are some answers where I do it: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73618/4999),
[here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66582/4999),
[here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27984/4999),
[here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100379/4999), and
[here (3D)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64923/4999).  (I think there may be a better one, but it's proving elusive. Maybe [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64161/4999).)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for all those very in depth responses.  I'm especially intrigued by the second one you list above.  If I'm understanding correctly, that function `implicitCurve` you construct there seems to be perfect for me, right?  Given that my curve above can possibly deform to not be a function of $x$.  Do you think it will be a problem that my function above is defined using real and imaginary parts of other functions?  That was one issue I had with my attempt similar to your `findRootGrad`.